# How to bypass Cloudflare security check/Captcha using Axios or Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios, puppeteer, cloudflare

I'm web scraping a website. It was working fine till last week with Axios and cheerio. I believe the website added Cloudflare check and now I'm not able to web **scrape**. How can I bypass that check/captcha using Axios/Puppeteer or if any other solution is available. I'm using it in a JS project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please show the website and your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely going to need a little more information from you before I'm able to provide some help. Is the website using Google's reCaptcha? Is it using hCaptcha? Is it using some other sort of captcha? Also, is there a submit button with the cloudflare check or does the page automatically submit when you solve the captcha? All of these questions would have an impact on how to solve this issue.